# How can I capture all request URLs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

When I make a call to my server I want the url and parameters logged to the log or console.

I am able to capture all database requests by putting the code below in my Routes\api.php. Is it possible to do the same for HTTP requests?

```
//Capture sql statements
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
    error_log($query->sql);
});
```

Comment: There is an event Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched, maybe you can use that one? If not, I'd simply go with a middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make it in middleware

create new middleware

**App\Http\Middleware\LogRoutes.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class LogRoutes
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->getRequestUri());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

then add in **app\Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // first in this array!
        App\Http\Middleware\LogRoutes::class,
        ...
    ]
]
```